# I'm validating XML against XSD in Windows Forms using C# .NET and it's giving me the error "Please Suggest the fix"

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm validating XML against XSD in Windows Forms using C# .NET and it's giving me the error "Please Suggest the fix"

Here is my code

```
namespace XMLValidation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Validation Error Count
        static int ErrorsCount = 0;

        // Validation Error Message
        static string ErrorMessage = "";

        public static void ValidationHandler(object sender,
                                             ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + args.Message + "\r\n";
            ErrorsCount++;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Hit.xml");

            Validate(doc1.ToString());

        }

        public void Validate(string strXMLDoc)
        {
            try
            {
                // Declare local objects
                XmlTextReader tr = null;
                XmlSchemaCollection xsc = null;
                XmlValidatingReader vr = null;

                // Text reader object
                tr = new XmlTextReader("C:\\ScreeningReport.xsd");
                xsc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
                xsc.Add(null, tr);

                // XML validator object

                vr = new XmlValidatingReader(strXMLDoc,
                             XmlNodeType.Document, null);

                vr.Schemas.Add(xsc);

                // Add validation event handler

                vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                vr.ValidationEventHandler +=
                         new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

                // Validate XML data

                while (vr.Read()) ;

                vr.Close();

                // Raise exception, if XML validation fails
                if (ErrorsCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
                }

                // XML Validation succeeded
                MessageBox.Show("XML validation succeeded.\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                // XML Validation failed
                MessageBox.Show("XML validation failed." + "\r\n" +
                "Error Message: " + error.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My XML file**

```
<ScreeningReport xmlns="http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0">
<DocumentIDGroup>
    <DocumentID schemeID="CorrelationID" schemeAgencyID="TRACKER">5500209_1</DocumentID>
  </DocumentIDGroup>
  <ScreeningPackageResult>
    <ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails>
      <PersonLegalID schemeAgencyName="" schemeAgencyID="AG" schemeName="SSN" schemeID="">346455645</PersonLegalID>
      <PersonName>
        <GivenName>Testfn</GivenName>
        <FamilyName>Testln</FamilyName>
      </PersonName>
      <BirthDateDetails>
        <YearMonthDate>1980-01-01</YearMonthDate>
      </BirthDateDetails>
    </ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails>
    <ScreeningUserDetails>
      <UserID>CRIMT</UserID>
    </ScreeningUserDetails>
    <ScreeningResult>
      <IDGroup>
        <ID schemeID="CorrelationID" schemeAgencyID="TRACKER">5500209_1</ID>
        <ID schemeID="OrderID" schemeAgencyID="TRACKER">5500209</ID>
        <ID schemeID="ScreeningID" schemeAgencyID="TRACKER">5911635</ID>
      </IDGroup>
      <ScreeningStatusDetails>
        <ScreeningOrderStatusCode>Hit</ScreeningOrderStatusCode>
        <Score>ExactMatch</Score>
      </ScreeningStatusDetails>
      <Ordered>true</Ordered>
      <Count>1</Count>
      <CriminalReport>
        <CriminalCase>
          <IDGroup>
            <ID schemeID="Case" schemeAgencyID="AG">57675</ID>
          </IDGroup>
          <JurisdictionType>County</JurisdictionType>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <CountrySubdivisionCode>AK</CountrySubdivisionCode>
          <CountyName>DENALI</CountyName>
          <ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails>
            <PersonLegalID schemeAgencyID="AG" schemeName="SSN">346455645</PersonLegalID>
            <PersonName>
              <GivenName>Testfn</GivenName>
              <FamilyName>Testln</FamilyName>
            </PersonName>
            <BirthDateDetails>
              <YearMonthDate>1980-01-01</YearMonthDate>
            </BirthDateDetails>
          </ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails>
          <Charge>
            <IDGroup>
              <ID schemeID="Charge" schemeAgencyID="AG">7546</ID>
              <ID schemeID="ConvictedOffenseCode" schemeAgencyID="AG" />
              <ID schemeID="StatuteNumber" schemeAgencyID="AG" />
            </IDGroup>
            <ChargeOrComplaint>test charge</ChargeOrComplaint>
            <Disposition>disp1</Disposition>
            <AdditionalItems qualifier="Parsed">
              <UserArea>
                <ChargeInfo>
                  <ChargeType>Conviction</ChargeType>
                  <ChargeLevel>Felony</ChargeLevel>
                  <Sentences />
                </ChargeInfo>
                <SterlingFields>
                  <Field name="Convicted Offense Description">test charge</Field>
                </SterlingFields>
              </UserArea>
            </AdditionalItems>
            <AdditionalItems qualifier="ParsedSentence">
              <UserArea>
                <SterlingFields>
                  <Field name="Enhanced Firearm Penalty">test charge</Field>
                </SterlingFields>
              </UserArea>
            </AdditionalItems>
            <AdditionalItems qualifier="ParsedCharge">
              <UserArea>
                <SterlingFields>
                  <Field name="ChargeCHARGE_LEVEL_ID">Felony</Field>
                </SterlingFields>
              </UserArea>
            </AdditionalItems>
          </Charge>
          <AdditionalItems qualifier="Parsed">
            <UserArea>
              <CaseInfo>
                <CaseArrestDate>
                  <YearMonthDate>2011-02-08</YearMonthDate>
                </CaseArrestDate>
                <CaseDispositionDate>
                  <YearMonthDate>2011-02-02</YearMonthDate>
                </CaseDispositionDate>
                <CaseStatus>Closed Case</CaseStatus>
                <ReportingDecision>DO_NOT_REPORT</ReportingDecision>
                <Sentences>
                  <Sentence>
                    <Type>Costs</Type>
                    <Suspended>false</Suspended>
                    <FineAmount>123</FineAmount>
                    <OtherInfo>suspended fine=123</OtherInfo>
                  </Sentence>
                </Sentences>
                <CaseType>Conviction</CaseType>
                <CaseLevel>Felony</CaseLevel>
              </CaseInfo>
            </UserArea>
          </AdditionalItems>
          <AdditionalItems qualifier="ParsedCriminalCase">
            <UserArea>
              <SterlingFields>
                <Field name="CriminalCaseAdditionalInfo">additional ionfo text</Field>
                <Field name="CriminalCaseGovernmentID">346455645</Field>
                <Field name="CriminalCaseReportDecision">DO NOT REPORT</Field>
                <Field name="CriminalCasePossibleRecord">false</Field>
              </SterlingFields>
            </UserArea>
          </AdditionalItems>
        </CriminalCase>
      </CriminalReport>
      <AdditionalItems qualifier="FulfillmentType">
        <UserArea>
          <Text>MANUAL</Text>
        </UserArea>
      </AdditionalItems>
      <AdditionalItems qualifier="ResearcherType">
        <UserArea>
          <Text>Internal</Text>
        </UserArea>
      </AdditionalItems>
      <AdditionalItems qualifier="TrackerUserId">
        <UserArea>
          <Text>ed</Text>
        </UserArea>
      </AdditionalItems>
    </ScreeningResult>
  </ScreeningPackageResult>
</ScreeningReport>
```

**My XSD**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <!-- top level screening result definition -->
    <xsd:element name="ScreeningReport" type="ScreeningReportType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningReportType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DocumentIDGroup" type="DocumentIDGroupType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningPackageResult" type="ScreeningPackageResultType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningException" type="ScreeningExceptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- document ID according to the new hrxml/oagis specifications -->
    <xsd:complexType name="DocumentIDGroupType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DocumentID" type="DocumentIDType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- single document id specification, according to the hrxml/oagis specification -->
    <xsd:complexType name="DocumentIDType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeAgencyID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!--
      top level package container for screenings
      (or batch in IFN terminology)
    -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningPackageResultType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails" type="ScreeningSubjectPersonDetailsType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningUserDetails" type="ScreeningUserDetailsType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CompletionDate" type="CompletionDateType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningOptionCode" type="ScreeningOptionCodeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningResult" type="ScreeningResultType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningException" type="ScreeningExceptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- optional codes to tweak the screening request -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningOptionCodeType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the screening client -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningUserDetailsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the completion date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="CompletionDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- the individual screening (or result in IFN terminology) -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningResultType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="IDGroup" type="IDGroupType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningException" type="ScreeningExceptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningStatusDetails" type="ScreeningStatusDetailsType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Ordered" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Count" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element name="CriminalReport" type="CriminalReportType"/>
                <xsd:element name="SanctionReport" type="SanctionReportType"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="AdditionalItems" type="AdditionalItemsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- sanction report -->
    <xsd:complexType name="SanctionReportType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="SubjectConfirmationMethodCode" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- an exception on the individual result -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningExceptionType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ExceptionIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ExceptionSeverity" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ExceptionMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ExceptionPath" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- status type -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningStatusDetailsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningOrderStatusCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningResultCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Score" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="StatusDate" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- grouping of IDs according to the new hrxml/oagis specifications -->
    <xsd:complexType name="IDGroupType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ID" type="IDType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- single id specification, according to the hrxml/oagis specification -->
    <xsd:complexType name="IDType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeAgencyID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- criminal report type definition -->
    <xsd:complexType name="CriminalReportType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CriminalCase" type="CriminalCaseType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CriminalCaseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="IDGroup" type="IDGroupType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ArrestingAgency" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="JurisdictionType" type="JurisdictionTypeEnumType"/>
            <xsd:element name="CourtName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CourtType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CourtJurisdiction" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CountryCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CountrySubdivisionCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CountyName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CityName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeTypeClassification" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseFileDate" type="CaseFileDateType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="SubjectConfirmation" type="SubjectConfirmationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails" type="ScreeningSubjectPersonDetailsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Charge" type="ChargeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="AdditionalItems" type="AdditionalItemsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the Subject Confirmation -->
    <xsd:complexType name="SubjectConfirmationType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ConfirmByFamilyName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ConfirmByGivenName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ConfirmByMiddleName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ConfirmByDateOfBirth" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the charge date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ChargeType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="IDGroup" type="IDGroupType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeOrComplaint" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeTypeClassification" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeClassification" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ArrestDate" type="ArrestDateType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeDate" type="ChargeDateType"/>
            <xsd:element name="OffenseDate" type="OffenseDateType"/>
            <xsd:element name="Sentence" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="SentenceDate" type="SentenceDateType"/>
            <xsd:element name="Disposition" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="DispositionDate" type="DispositionDateType"/>
            <xsd:element name="ProbationStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="AdditionalItems" type="AdditionalItemsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the disposition date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="DispositionDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the arrest date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ArrestDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the charge date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ChargeDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the case file date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="CaseFileDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the offense date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="OffenseDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the sentence date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="SentenceDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- *********************** REFACTOR **************************** -->
    <!-- details about the subject for the screening -->
    <xsd:complexType name="ScreeningSubjectPersonDetailsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ScreeningSubjectDetailsTypeCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PersonLegalID" type="PersonIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PersonName" type="PersonNameType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PostalAddress" type="PostalAddressType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="GenderCode" type="GenderCodeEnumType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="BirthDateDetails" type="BirthDateDetailsType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="RaceCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="EyeColor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="HairColor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Height" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Weight" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Age" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Licenses" type="LicensesType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- licenses -->
    <xsd:complexType name="LicensesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="License" type="LicenseType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="LicenseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="LicenseName" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="IssuingAuthority" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- postal address -->
    <xsd:complexType name="PostalAddressType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="AddressLine" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="CityName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CountrySubDivisionCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <!-- state/province ISO code -->
            <xsd:element name="CountryCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PostalCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the personal legal id -->
    <xsd:complexType name="PersonIDType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:normalizedString">
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeID" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="optional"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeName" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeAgencyID" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="optional"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="schemeAgencyName" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!--
      gender enumeration from the hrxml-3.0 spec
      http://ns.hr-xml.org/3.0/documentation/components/GenderCode-element.php
     -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="GenderCodeEnumType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="9"/>
            <!-- not known -->
            <!-- male -->
            <!-- female -->
            <!-- not specified -->
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="JurisdictionTypeEnumType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="National"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="State"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="County"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Federal District"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Local District"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- generic name reference -->
    <xsd:complexType name="PersonNameType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="FormattedName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="GivenName" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="MiddleName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="FamilyName" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- details for the birth date -->
    <xsd:complexType name="BirthDateDetailsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- additional details -->
    <xsd:complexType name="AdditionalItemsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="UserArea" type="UserAreaType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="vendor" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="qualifier" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- user area definition -->
    <!--
    <xsd:complexType name="UserAreaType" block="restriction">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice/>
            <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    -->
    <xsd:complexType name="UserAreaType" block="restriction">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeInfo" type="ChargeInfoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseInfo" type="CaseInfoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="UserInfo" type="UserInfoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="SterlingFields" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                                    </xsd:extension>
                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="ChargeInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ChargeLevel" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Sentences" type="SentencesType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="SentencesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Sentence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Consecutive" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="LengthMonths" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="LengthDays" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="LengthHours" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="LengthYears" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="LengthWeeks" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="MappedSentenceType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Suspended" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="FineAmount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="OtherInfo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CaseInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CaseArrestDate" type="CaseArrestDateType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseDispositionDate" type="CaseDispositionDateType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseDisposition" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseStatus" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ReportingDecision" type="ReportingDecisionEnumType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ReportingDecisionRule" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="ReportingDecisionRuleBlurb" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Sentences" type="SentencesType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="CaseLevel" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CaseArrestDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CaseDispositionDateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="YearMonthDate" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ReportingDecisionEnumType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="REPORT"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DO_NOT_REPORT"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CONTACT_CLIENT_UNORDERED_HIT"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CONTACT_CLIENT_NO_SALARY"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DATA_ERROR"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="UserInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The error is:

> The element 'CriminalCase' in namespace 'http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0' has invalid child element 'ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails' in namespace 'http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0:CityName http://www.sterlingtesting.com/hrxml/1.0:ChargeTypeClassification'.

ScreeningSubjectPersonDetails is the child element. Why is it showing INVALID CHILD?

Answer (score 4):

Do you really believe anyone is going to read through this ***HUGE*** pile of code?
Anyway, the error message simply says that your XML file doesn't conform to the XSD...